# how to sum an amount above a specified number in Excel

Tags: excel

i am working with a table where all the values above 145 are marked red. i want to add only the amount greater than 145 in these values. e.g if i have 150 in one cell and 150 in other cell the result would be 10. i tried using `sumif` but it add all the numbers above 145. i can use `if` formula to calculate the values above 145 and then add them but i will have to make another table for that. if there a formula to cover this in one step so i dont have to make a separate table? i have to do this for every column.

[image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF()` with `COUNTIF()` and subtraction.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,">145")-145*COUNTIF(A1:A100,">145")
```

[image]